# What will be the setup process for website development?

Tags: python

I want to create a simple site for my personal usage. And this only in python based technologies. So I want to get a expert oponian on this topic.

1. What should i used as platform? I did a search for available options and found `Django`, `grok`, `web2py` and many more of these. Which one a novice use should use? If I choose to use only the basic python scripts then what option i have to work on?
2. http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming. This link on python site confused me more, instead of solving my curiosity about the topic. Please give some pointer to accurate and easy to understand reading materials.

I have got a idea of developing `java` based web applications using either `spring-webmvc` and `struts`. Can I relate Java process to python process for web development?

Comment: Re: #2 - that's for making a web **browser**, not a web **site**. It's not relevant to what you want to do.

Comment: Are you a novice at website programming in general, or just making a website using python?

Comment: HI Ryan, I am new to website programming in general. Please give me some some good read-up resources. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the size of the community matters to you above everything else go consider that PHP has at least 10x more users than any Python framework.

If you have an existing database and you do not want to move data over to a new one, you probably should use SQLAlchemy and therefore you need a glued framework (Pylons in the best in that case). Since glued framework are built using third party components they tend to have less integration than full-stack frameworks.

If you are starting an app from scratch a full-stack framework, like Django and web2py, is the best options. Django gives you a better looking database administrative interface. web2py instead gives you something easier to start with, a web based IDE and the option to run code unmodified on the Google cloud.

web2py is the only framework that promises backward compatibility and never broke it. I do not know if that is an issue to you.

The official [online web2py documentation](http://web2py.com/book) includes the entire web2py book (350 pages).

Avoid smaller frameworks that are still under development because APIs will change and because they miss a lot of the features that bigger frameworks have.

[This](http://www.tenthrow.com/home/) was built with web2py.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend You the django framework. Why? Because of big community, thought architecture and really many applications for it (something like plugins in jquery).

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to web programming in general, then I'd recommend trying [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/). It's based on django, free, and is really easy to get started.